# Action bar. Кастомизация

Tags: android, java

Здравствуйте!
Возможно ли сделать экшнбар с табами, которые можно выравнивать, например, по центру или по правому краю и т.д.? Можно ли задать ширину табов?

Comment: http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/an-expandable-action-using-custom-action-provider-in-pre-honeycomb-versions-using-sherlock-library/ можно самому сделать вид ActionBar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
   public View actionBarSetCustom(int layout, Context context) {
            actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
            actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
            actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
            actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
            actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
            actionBarView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(layout, null);
            actionBar.setCustomView(actionBarView);
        return actionBarView;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Да, можно. Используйте для этого `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar`
Пример:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="@dimen/triple_height_toolbar"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" >

<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
//разметка

</RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

потом чтоб его использовать в AppCompatActivity нужно добавить:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```